# What does ellipsis in CoffeeScript mean?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to rewrite the following statement from Coffeescript to Javascript:

`d.data.name[0..1].toLowerCase()`

Can someone please tell me what this statement means?

Comment: This is a documented feature: http://coffeescript.org/#slices

Comment: @GregHewgill: Thank you. I did not know what to search for :)

Comment: You can try everything out [here](http://coffeescript.org/).

Comment: @Legend: I searched for `0..` in the documentation. Sure enough, that was the example.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Yeap. That "Thank You" was for both documentation and the name.

Comment: I would have thought that an Ellipsis is 3 dots in a row rather than 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Ranges can also be used to extract slices of arrays. With two dots (3..6), the range is inclusive (3, 4, 5, 6); with three dots (3...6), the range excludes the end (3, 4, 5).

http://coffeescript.org/#slices

So this:

```
d.data.name[0..1].toLowerCase()
```

Translates to this:

```
d.data.name.slice(0, 1).toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 3):

`..` This features is inspired from Ruby and are called ranges.

```
d.data.name[0..1].toLowerCase() # turns the first character to lowercase
```

More details [here](http://elegantcode.com/2011/08/02/exploring-coffeescript-part-5-ranges-loops-and-comprehensions/).